# Invalid Schema or missing namespace

Tags: xml, xsd, namespaces

I am new to this and starting all from scratch, so I wrote an example of xml code and then created the schema. So, the sytax is checked and correct, what I constantly get as an error is the following: "Invalid schema or missing namespace". This pops up when I am trying to validate.
I will need this schema afterwards to import it into another schema, but I cannot do that yet, due to the error.
I understand the concept of the "namespaces" (I guess), but I am still stumbling upon.

Here is my schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace= "http://www.w3.org/ns/data/"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xsd:element name="companyDataModel" type="complexType">
    <xsd:complextype name="contactInfo">
        <xsd:simpletype name="phone"
                        type="string"
                        use="optional">
            <xsd:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xsd:length value="30"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpletype>
        <xsd:simpletype name="mobile"
                        type="string"
                        use="optional">
            <xsd:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xsd:length value="30"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpletype>
        <xsd:simpletype name="e-mail"
                        type="string"
                        use="required">
            <xsd:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xsd:length value="100"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpletype>
        <xsd:simpletype name="facebookID"
                        type="string"
                        use="optional">
            <xsd:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xsd:length value="100"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpletype>
    </xsd:complextype>
    <xsd:complextype name="personalInfo">
        <xsd:simpletype name="firstname"
                        type="string">
            <xsd:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xsd:length value="30"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpletype>
        <xsd:simpletype name="middleName"
                        type="string">
            <xsd:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xsd:length value="30"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpletype>
        <xsd:simpletype name="lastName"
                        type="string">
            <xsd:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xsd:length value="30"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpletype>
        <xsd:simpletype name="gender"
                        type="string">
            <xsd:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xsd:length value="1"/>
                <xsd:pattern value="F|M"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpletype>
    </xsd:complextype>
    <xsd:complextype name="addressInfo">
        <xsd:simpletype name="street"
                        type="string">
            <xsd:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xsd:length value="50"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpletype>
        <xsd:simpletype name="number"
                        type="string">
            <xsd:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xsd:length value="50"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpletype>
        <xsd:simpletype name="city"
                        type="string">
            <xsd:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xsd:length value="50"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpletype>
        <xsd:simpletype name="country"
                        type="string">
            <xsd:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xsd:length value="50"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpletype>
    </xsd:complextype>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

and here is the test xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<companyDataModel xmlns ="http://www.w3.org/ns/data/">
    <contactInfo>
        <phone>12345</phone>
        <mobile>54321</mobile>
        <email>test@gmail.com</email>
        <facebook>fbid</facebook>
    </contactInfo>
    
    <personalInfo>
        <firstname>Anna</firstname>
        <lastname>Karenina</lastname>
        <middlename>Hanns</middlename>
        <gender>F</gender>
    </personalInfo>

    <addressInfo>
        <street>Wall Street</street>
        <number>25</number>
        <city>New York</city>
        <country>United States</country>
    </addressInfo>

</companyDataModel>
```

Comment: That schema is indeed not valid, as you can see in any introduction (like https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#DefnDeclars) it is `xsd:complexType` and not `xsd:complextype`. And the way you mix/nest complex and simple type declarations to intent to declare the elements with simple types is also wrong, you need an `xsd:element`, either with `name` or with `ref`. And the wrapper for that is an `xsd:sequence` or `xsd:choice`. So start with a tutorial like that primer and take it step by step (or use an XML editor which usually allows you to infer/generate a schema and/or has a schema editor).

Comment: To add to that, the idea of using namespaces containing a domain name like www.w3.org is to enable you to choose a namespace that indicates ownership. Either put your namespace in a domain that you control, or just call it "foo-bar". Or don't use namespaces at all.